# How to generate pdf if our column less than the declared table column

Tags: c#, itext

I have declared a table with 50 columns and I pass only 40 column data. In this case pdf not generates .Pdf generates, only if I pass 50 column data. how can I solve this issue? I found a function to solve this problem but I forget that function name. Anybody help me...

eg: it works,

```
 PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(50);
 for (int i = 1; i <=50; i++)
   {
      table1.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
      table1.AddCell(new Phrase(new Phrase("100", font4)));
  }
```

which is not working is,

```
PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(50);
for (int i = 1; i <=40; i++)
   {
      table1.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
      table1.AddCell(new Phrase(new Phrase("100", font4)));
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem using `table1.CompleteRow();` in the last line. The o/p is,

[image]`

Hope it helps some one...